# How to set hostname in MySQL? (OS X)

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, virtualhost, hostname

I want to do something similar to the `hosts` file in MySQL, where I can associate an IP address with a given hostname. So `localhost` has a default IP address of `127.0.0.1`, and let's say I have another hostname called `anotherHost` with an IP address of `192.xx.xxx.xxx`, which is defined in `/etc/hosts`.

I want to be able to create a user in MySQL by a command like `Create user 'johndoe'@'anotherHost';` and have the 'anotherHost' part resolve to its corresponding IP address. As opposed to entering the entire IP address for that user. There is a `plist` file associated with my MySQL download so I'm wondering if there is some property that I can set inside it that would enable this. I'm just not sure what the syntax is.

Comment: You'll thank yourself later for *not* taking this route. In MySQL, `'monty'@'thishost'` and `'monty'@'thathost'` are two separate and *entirely unrelated* accounts, potentially with different passwords and privileges, and nothing in common except the coincidentally-same username.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not a reasonable thing to do. You need to work with a DNS infrastructure to get name resolution working to spec. There is no possibility of doing what you want, how you want, nor should there be.

Now, having said that in as stern a dad-voice as I can muster, if this is a common thing that you perform at your shell, then you need to make a shell function that makes short work of your common task. Something like `msqladd user host database` that will then interpret that into the correct SQL statement for the given database.

Comment: `CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';` (an example given in MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html)) implies that `localhost` will be resolved into its corresponding IP address. Why is it unreasonable for other hostnames?

Comment: @user3004041 It's not unreasonable for other hostnames to resolve to an IP address. What's unreasonable is the methods you're proposing. If a hostname doesn't resolve to the IP address you want, then you need to make that hostname... _resolve to the IP address you want._ Properly using DNS.